# Graph with fix origin

Tags: java, swing, graph

I m drawing a graph with swing, and i would like to set a fixed origin, that is when i scaled the graph, only the horizontal and vertical label from the axis are updated.
Here is what i have until now:

```
protected void drawAxis(Graphics2D g2) {
    double axisH = yPositionToPixel(originY);
    double axisV = xPositionToPixel(originX);

    g2.drawLine(0, (int) axisH, getWidth(), (int) axisH);
    g2.drawLine((int) axisV, 0, (int) axisV, getHeight());
}

protected double yPositionToPixel(double position) {
    double height = (double) getHeight();
    return height - ((position) * (height) / (maxY));
}

protected double xPositionToPixel(double position) {
    return (position) * (double) getWidth() / (maxX);
}
```

When i zoom for exemple the origin is recalculated, so the graph is moving from its original place.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your origin is at point `(originX,originY)` in your graph space but `(pixelOriginY,pixelOriginX)` in the screen space. Then the following transformations apply:

```
protected double yPositionToPixel(double position) {
    double height = (double) getHeight();
    return pixelOriginY - (position-originY) / (maxY-originY) * (height-pixelOriginY);
}

protected double xPositionToPixel(double position) {
    double width = (double) getWidth();
    return pixelOriginX + (position-originX) / (maxX-originX) * (width-pixelOriginX);
}
```

In case you set the origin to `(0,0)` and `(0,height)` on your screen you'll get back your equations. Therefore I assume your origin is not at `(0,0)` and thus you have to define this additional point where your origin should be in the screen space.